# Функция appendChild JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте есть javascript функция которая вызывается при нажатии кнопки. При его выполнении в веб консоли выдаётся ошибка: TypeError: newsScroll.appendChild is not a function. Вот код:

```js
function createNews(authorNames, newsContent){
    var newsScroll = document.getElementsByClassName("newsScroll");
    var newsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newsDiv.classList.add("news");
    newsScroll.appendChild(newsDiv);
    return newsDiv;
}
```

Скриншоты:
[image: Выводы в консоли]

Comment: я бы написал newsDiv.classList.add("news"); для начала.

Comment: Я изменил. Ошибка осталась.

Comment: Вы элемент newsScroll берёте по имени класса. У вас элементов с этим классом много на странице?

Comment: Я добавил скриншоты

Comment: Вам уже ответили, что если на странице несколько таких дивов с классом newsScroll, то в переменной у вас будет не один элемент, а массив элементов и у него нет метода appendChild.
А вместо document.getElementsByClassName("newsScroll") лучше использовать document.querySelectorAll(".newsScroll")

Comment: Спасибо! Ошибки пропали всё работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причин может быть множество.

Например у вас несколько элементов с классом .newsScroll в этом случае var newsScroll массив с [0] [1] [2] у массива функции appendChild не будет.

document.getElementsByClassName("newsScroll") в целом не существует (не найден)

и куча других причин, это гадание на кофейной...

попробуйте вывести в консоль console.log() newsScroll и посмотреть чем он является через DevTools Chrome либо более детально опишите вопрос (больше кода с HTML примером).

Comment: getElementsByClassName
вернет elemetnS а не element как например document.getElementById()
ваша проблема в этом.
document.getElementsByClassName('newsScroll')[0] должно помочь.